# Symbolic manipulation of functional form

Tags: polynomials, expression-manipulation

I have a functional polynomial expression of the form:

```
expr = f[x] + f[x] g[w] + Conjugate[f[y]] g[z] +
       Conjugate[g[z]] + g[w] + f[x] f[y] g[w] + 1 +
       Conjugate[a] f[t] + Conjugate[b] Conjugate[c]
```

I would like to write a function that selects terms that are up to linear (i.e. zero and first order) in the functions `f` and `g`, eg. in my case the correct output would be:

```
1 + f[x] + Conjugate[g[z]] + g[w] + Conjugate[a] f[t] +
Conjugate[b] Conjugate[c]
```

Note that the functions are complex, and the conjugate terms are also considered. I basically just want to neglect second-order terms and higher.

Comment: You could build rules as in : `expr /. {f[x_] f[y_] -> 0, g[x_] g[y_] -> 0}`.

Comment: the expression i put is just a simplification, in the general case it contains a lot more terms with much higher orders, so i would need very many rules

Comment: Take the Jacobian, zero everything as for the constant term just zero everything in the initial expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this

```
Replace[Expand@expr, Times[terms__ /; Count[{terms}, _f | _g, Infinity] > 1] -> 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
(Series[Simplify[expr/.{forg_[x_] -> m forg[x]}, m \[Element] Reals], {m, 0, 1}] // Normal) /. m -> 1
```

Edit:

If there are other functions within the expression that are not `f` or `g` then you have to be a bit more explicit:

```
(Series[Simplify[expr/.{f[x_] -> m f[x],g[x_]->m g[x]}, m \[Element] Reals], {m, 0, 1}] // Normal) /. m -> 1
```

Comment: thanks, this works for the above example, but unfortunately my (*real*) expression also has terms of the form: Conjugate[a]*f[t] and Conjugate[b]*Conjugate[c], for which it fails

Comment: @user4794, the edit should solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

First harvest the terms:

```
terms = Cases[expr, (_f | _g) | Conjugate[_g | _f], Infinity]//Union
```

and then

```
(D[expr, {terms}] /. {f -> (0 &), g -> (0 &)}).terms + (expr/.Thread[terms -> 0])
```

Note:

For a faster alternative use `CoefficientArrays`:

```
#1 + #2.terms & @@ (Take[CoefficientArrays[expr, terms], 2] // Normal)
```